# Java Arrays.binarySearch(Object[], int, int, Object) Signature Not Recognized

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, signature, binary-search

I'm trying to use the binarySearch method documented at the [Java API Specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) but my IDE, Eclipse (Helios), is not recognizing the signature.

My class, boiled down to its 2 data members and the method in which I'm trying to call the Arrays.binarySearch:

```
import java.util.Arrays; // Access Arrays class
public class SortedStringArrayList {
    // member data
    private String[] items;
    private int size;

    // methods
    public int testBinSearch(String item) {
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(items, 0, size, item);
    }
}
```

When I code in the method, Eclipse assumes I want a different signature and tells me:

> The method binarySearch(int[], int) in
>   the type Arrays is not applicable for
>   the arguments (String[], int, int,
>   String)

The signatures for binarySearch it suggested as available were:

[image]

I'm very new to Java/Eclipse. Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell Eclipse to use Java 1.6 (under project settings). I'm guessing you're on 1.5. 1.5 and older versions only have the basic version of `binarySearch`, with no `fromIndex` or `toIndex`.

If you want users with older JREs to be able to run your program, you could copy the `binarySearch` implementations from [the 1.6 source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html) and paste it into your own code.

Comment: This sounds entirely plausible. 1.5 to 1.6 didn't change a _ton_, but where it did, reading the wrong docs is a major gotcha.

Comment: The Javadocs do say `Since: 1.6`, but it's subtle and easy to overlook.

Comment: Thanks all! I was indeed on 1.5.